# how to open an empty buffer when vim on directory?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I have nerdtree and ctrlp installed in vim.
I use vim in command line on some directory: vim somedir.
I intend to let vim start with an empty file just as if I only type vim. 
But currently, vim will start with nerdtree opened, the root directory is the same as the directory after vim command.

How can let vim start with an empty buffer and afterwards I want to use ctrlp to search files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do it the other way around:

```
$ cd somedir && vim
```

Comment: If you don't want to change directory in your shell, you can wrap in parentheses: `(cd somedir && vim)`. The directory is changed in subshell for vim, and the current shell doesn't care. If you don't want to create a subshell, let Vim change the directory: `vim "+cd somedir"`.